# Recommended way to run Apache Geode as a service on Windows

Tags: gemfire, geode

I need to run locators and services on two W2K8 Windows servers. Normally I use [nssm](http://nssm.cc/) to run Java based applications by calling their respective `java -jar` call from nssm. But Geode uses gfsh.

What is the best practice ? One could use the [API](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/geode/managing/management/gfsh_and_management_api.html) to spawn an instance and run the necessary start commands:

```
commandService = CommandService.createLocalCommandService(cache);
CommandStatement showDeadLocksCmdStmt = commandService.createCommandStatement
    ("start locator ...");
if (showDeadlocksResult.hasIncomingFiles()) {
    showDeadlocksResult.saveIncomingFiles(System.getProperty("user.dir") + 
                  "/commandresults");
}
```

Or one could mimic the behavior of `gfsh.bat` and create one NSSM service for each functionality (locator and server) which runs the same the batch does and pass the necessary command:

```
java -Dgfsh=true -Dlog4j.configurationFile=classpath:log4j2-cli.xml -classpath C:\dev\apache-geode-1.1.1\lib\gfsh-dependencies.jar org.apache.geode.management.internal.cli.Launcher start locator ...
```

Judging from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43742425/apache-geode-9-0-3-locator-could-not-find-a-jmx-manager) question doing it `gfsh`y is recommended

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gfsh -e` to [run GFSH from command line](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/114/tools_modules/gfsh/os_command_line_execution.html)